# Python Webdriver -unexpected EOF while parsing (<string>, line 1)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Python with webdriver

I'm trying to locate element with find element with xpath and get :"unexpected EOF while parsing (, line 1)"

When I try to locate it by finding element with class name, it works well.

The problem is that I can't use it since I have several classes with the same name.

Here is xpath:

```
//*[@id="j_id0:j_id5:j_id6:j_id36"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/svg/g/g[1]/path[1]
```

here is the class name : st0

here is my code line:

```
ss = self.SELENIUM_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_id0:j_id5:j_id6:j_id36"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/svg/g/g[1]/path[1]')
```

-Which does not work

```
ddd = self.SELENIUM_DRIVER.find_element_by_class_name('st0')
```

-Which works

This is the html:

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your actual HTML is probably larger (containing `div`, `ul` and other tags). If your entire HTML is just a `<path ...></path>`, then you can use the xpath `//path[1]`. If that works, you can add more and more tags to the HTML, and make the xpath longer, until it stops working. From that you know which part of the xpath has the error. If you still can't figure out how to fix the error, add it to the question, like this: xpath ... works, xpath ... causes the error.

Comment: As an aside, that is a very scary XPath. If you use that in a test it is guaranteed to be very brittle.

Comment: Sorry, but i didnt understand you suggestio.Are you saying to set xpath //path[1] and that is it ?

Comment: I tried to set xpath to //path[1] but it does not work

Comment: @ohad try once this xpath `//*[@id = 'j_id0:j_id5:j_id6:j_id36']/descendant::path[1]`..and let me know..

Comment: HI Saurabh Gaur- Sorry still get "unexpected EOF while parsing (<string>, line 1)" ....ddd = self.SELENIUM_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id = "j_id0:j_id5:j_id6:j_id36"]/descendant::path[1]')

Comment: Any other suggestions? when i found with class name i managed to find but have several classes with same name, so i'm getting element that i dont want.Any posiblity to use index in class ? somthing like?   __ ddd = self.SELENIUM_DRIVER.find_element_by_class_name('st0'[1]).value_of_css_property('fill')

Comment: @ohad try with the given answer and let me know...:)

Answer (score 0):

The following query will look for a `path` with the parent tree of `div/svg/g/g[1]`, with a class equalling `st0` and at index `[1]`:

```
self.SELENIUM_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath('//div/svg/g/g[1]/path[@class=st0][1]')
```

If the parent tree is unique from earlier on, it may be a good idea to make the query shorter, e.g.:

```
self.SELENIUM_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath('//g/g[1]/path[@class=st0][1]')
```

Comment: Hi.None of the above work :( .Would like to mention that the element im looking for is a picture\polygon.is it matter?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem with your provided Id `j_id0:j_id5:j_id6:j_id36` and as you are saying class name is same for some other elements as well, So you should try using `xpath` by passing index as below :-

```
self.SELENIUM_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath('(//path[@class=st0])[1]')
```

Now you can locate your desire element by just changing index value.

Hope it works...:)